# More formal way to say "No way!"?

Tags: phrase-requests

What would be a more formal way to say "No way!"? For example, in a business conference setting.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to @Mari-Lou A's link, [a quick google](https://www.google.com/search?q=No%20way%20definition&rlz=1CAXWWL_enGB813GB813&oq=no%20way%20&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i60j69i57j69i60j0.1302j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on) reveals two possibilities:

**under no circumstances**

[From Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&query=under%20no%20circumstances)

> Never, whatever the situation is or might be.

and

**not at all**

> definitely not

[Also from ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/not_at_all) (Google Dictionaries take all entries from here)

Comment: This assumes the intended meaning is "No way—not going to happen," as opposed to, "No way! Is that really true?"

Comment: @AleksandrH But the OP doesn't specify the intended meaning - it could be either, but I'm taking on this one because of the 'business meeting' part.

Comment: Good point, this meaning is more likely in a business context. OP needs to clarify, though.

Comment: @AleksandrH Indeed.  This'll probably get closed in the next couple of hours, as Mari-Lou has mentioned

Comment: Editing right now.

Answer (score 1):

The most formal way to say "no way" (as in: 'that cannot possibly be an accurate statement') is:

***"Surely, you jest."*** (Although it isn't used much, anymore.)

***"No way,"*** in the sense of 'that outcome is not possible'- in the context of a business conference - would probably be expressed as:

*"We will have to look into that."* AmE

Comment: It is probable that the OP is referring to the other definition of *No way!* - as in 'certainly not'.  See the comments of my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Some French has entered the English lexicon without ever losing their character as they remain unmistakably "French" to an English speaker. In French, **au contraire** means, literally, on the contrary, and that’s exactly what this loan phrase means in English. It’s often used to mean, roughly, **I beg to differ**, and it usually creates a humorous or sarcastic tone.

**Au contraire**:  [TFD](https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/au+contraire)

> To the contrary!

As in:  [Nat. English.com](https://eng.ichacha.net/hy/zaoju.aspx?q=au%20contraire&p=2)

> - **Au contraire**, says the author.
> - When people ask if Monica sullied the good name of interns, I say **au    contraire.**